# Does Blend have anything similar to the MsBuild BuildingInsideVisualStudio variable?

Tags: msbuild, blend

Does Blend have anything similar to the MsBuild BuildingInsideVisualStudio variable, which is set by Visual Studio when you build?

What I need it for is this: if we build we also run the unit tests and generate documentation, but not when we are inside Visual Studio. We accomplish this by adding among other things the following line to our .Targets file:

```
<AdditionalBuildTargets Condition="'$(AdditionalBuildTargets)' == '' And $(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' != 'true'">Test;Document</AdditionalBuildTargets>
```

This works fine when running in Visual Studio, but we want the same behavior in Blend. Blend does not set the BuildingInsideVisualStudio flag so this approach does not work. Does anyone know of a different solution?

Comment: BuildingInsideExpressionBlend ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out with the hint that Preet Sangha gave. The solution was

```
<AdditionalBuildTargets Condition="'$(AdditionalBuildTargets)' == '' And $(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' != 'true' And '$(BuildingInsideExpressionBlend)' != 'true'">Test;Document</AdditionalBuildTargets>
```